# How to select all meta values of certain meta_key's?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to make a query but I can't get the grips of it. I want to select all records by certain meta_keys. It works fine when i query by one meta key. But when I want to make the query by two meta_key's it's returning nothing. Can someone please help me?!

The query that works:

```php
SELECT *
FROM `uszc_users` AS u, `uszc_utilizatori_acord` AS ua, `uszc_usermeta` AS ub
WHERE ua.email = u.user_email
AND ub.user_id = u.id
AND ub.meta_key = 'first_name'
AND acord = 'DA'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And the query that returns nothing:

```php
SELECT *
FROM `uszc_users` AS u, `uszc_utilizatori_acord` AS ua, `uszc_usermeta` AS ub
WHERE ua.email = u.user_email
AND ub.user_id = u.id
AND ub.meta_key = 'first_name'
AND ub.meta_key = 'last_name'
AND acord = 'DA'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I have 3 tables, table uszc_usermeta contains first_name and last_name which are in the meta_value column both.

Comment: provide some sample of raw data and expected result

Comment: OMG you have 3 tables here?

Comment: Yes. I have 3 tables. Why?!

Comment: You should use proper `JOIN` syntax and `GROUP` somehow the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have any record with

```
AND ub.meta_key = 'first_name'
AND ub.meta_key = 'last_name'
```

That has no sense, so just that simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM `uszc_users` AS u, `uszc_utilizatori_acord` AS ua, `uszc_usermeta` AS ub
WHERE ua.email = u.user_email
AND ub.user_id = u.id
AND (ub.meta_key = 'first_name'
OR ub.meta_key = 'last_name')
AND acord = 'DA'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**UPDATE** Since the OP said that @bhelmet posted correct answer I want to clarify for OP how **good** query should look like imho:

```
SELECT u.*, ub.meta_value first_name, uc.meta_value last_name
FROM `uszc_users` AS u  
INNER JOIN `uszc_utilizatori_acord` AS ua
ON ua.email = u.user_email
  AND ua.acord = 'DA'
INNER JOIN  `uszc_usermeta` AS ub
ON ub.user_id = u.id
  AND ub.meta_key = 'first_name'
INNER JOIN `uszc_usermeta` AS uc
ON uc.user_id = u.id
  AND uc.meta_key = 'last_name'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: After using @bhelmet solution I have some problems. How would I select records if the meta_value column is twice in the table? The meta_values of meta_key: 'first_name' and 'last_name' are in two different meta_value columns now.

Comment: you have much more problems there, you just don't know about them yet :-)

Comment: Can you please help me?! Your updated query throws an error.

Comment: did you check the last one? there were some typos, but I believe I did fix them. What error do you have?

Comment: Now it works. Thanks man. I will accept this answer as the solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for all records where `meta_key` equals BOTH 'first_name' and 'last_name'. You probably want to do something like `AND ub.meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name')`.

```
SELECT *
FROM `uszc_users` AS u, `uszc_utilizatori_acord` AS ua, `uszc_usermeta` AS ub
WHERE ua.email = u.user_email
AND ub.user_id = u.id
AND ub.meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name')
AND acord = 'DA'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This is first returning all records with meta_key 'first_name' and after all of that it comes all the records with meta_key 'last_name'. I would like to be on the same row. Is that possible?

Comment: Edit your question to add more details, especially a sample of your desired output. A brief sample of the table structures would be useful as well.

Comment: I want the on the meta_value column to have the first name and the last name at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

To check two conditions for 'usermeta' you should join table twice. You need something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `uszc_users` AS u, `uszc_utilizatori_acord` AS ua, `uszc_usermeta` AS ub, `uszc_usermeta` AS uc
WHERE ua.email = u.user_email
AND ub.user_id = u.id
AND ub.meta_key = 'first_name'
AND uc.user_id = u.id
AND uc.meta_key = 'last_name'
AND acord = 'DA'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Oh, man, that works best for my needs. Thank you so much. But what if I need to select certain columns ?! Because now I get this error " #1052 - Column 'meta_value' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: I think it's because of same column name after using this query. How would I select records if the meta_value column is twice in the table? The meta_values of meta_key: 'first_name' and 'last_name' are in two different meta_value columns now.

Comment: @lonut I didn't quite get, if you use 'meta_values' with aliases (e.g. ub.meta_value and uc.meta_value) you should not get error for ambiguity.